# How to convert code AVFoundation objective c to Swift?

Tags: camera, avfoundation, swift, xcode6

I am using AVFoundation in swift for take pictures but I can't convert any func lines of code from objective c to Swift. My func code is:

```
 - (void) capImage { //method to capture image from AVCaptureSession video feed
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {

    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {

        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (videoConnection) {
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

    if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL) {
        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
        [self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    }
}];
```

}

This line send me error AnyObject[]does not conform to protocol sequencfe..:

```
 for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
```

In swift:

```
  for port:AnyObject in connection.inputPorts {
```

And I don't know how convert this line:

```
 [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
```

Can u help me to convert to swift?
Thanks!!

Comment: To learn more about the completion handler and converting them to swift look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190277/writing-handler-for-uialertaction/24190415#24190415

Answer (score 6):

```
for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) { )
```

Arrays of `AnyObject` should be cast to arrays of your actual type before interating, like this:

```
for (port in connection.inputPorts as AVCaptureInputPort[]) { }
```

In terms of blocks to closures, you just have to get the syntax correct.

```
stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
    (imageSampleBuffer, error) in // This line defines names the inputs
    //...
}
```

Note that this also uses [Trailing Closure Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_126). Do read up on the docs more!

EDIT: In terms of initializers, they now look like this:

```
let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageSampleBuffer)
self.processImage(UIImage(data:imageData))
```

Comment: and this??NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
            [self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]]; how to conveert in swift, I don't know how traduce, thanks!

Comment: great!! but have others errors same type in this method with cast types I have in objective c: CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);
        
        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; and swift: imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(smallImage as? CGImage!, cropRect) and obtain errors type..
        
        imageView2.image.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(imageRef)  thanks!

Comment: @user3745888 I think you should either edit your question to include these or create a new question with what you have and what errors you get. Try to be very clear!

Comment: for port in connection.inputPorts as [AVCaptureInputPort] {

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var videoConnection :AVCaptureConnection?
   if let videoConnection = self.stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
     self.stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (buffer:CMSampleBuffer!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
     if let exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(buffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, nil) {
         let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
         self.previewImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.previewImage.image, nil, nil, nil)
      }
     })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should answer the problem with the ports:

```
if let videoConnection = stillImageOuput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){//take a photo here}
```