# Swift Error : Use of module 'CMSampleBuffer' as a type

Tags: xcode, avfoundation, swift

I saw below question to use 'captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection' function in swift: 
[How to convert code AVFoundation objective c to Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288048/how-to-convert-code-avfoundation-objective-c-to-swift)

When I try to use a AVFoundation function as following:

```
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput!

//...Initialize stillImageOutput

stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(imageSampleBuffer, error) in
        if imageSampleBuffer {
            var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageSampleBuffer as CMSampleBuffer) // I get error on this line saying: 'Use of module ' CMSampleBuffer' as a type'
            self.processImage(UIImage(data: imageData))
        }
        })
```

I got the error on XCode, which says 'Use of module ' CMSampleBuffer' as a type'.
I tried to rewrite that same line multiple times with slightly different ways, but I could not figure out the solution.

Am I doing something wrong or is it possibly the shaky XCode Beta not working properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: looks like a bug to me. works if you `import CoreMedia`

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I think its not a bug, it doesn't recognize the type due to no `import CoreMedia`. Also, the typecast shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jack and @Christian's solutions worked for me.
I was not careful enough to **import CoreMedia**.
I never used this framework before, and did not know if the problem was due to not having imported a correct framework.
Thank you for your help!