# Can a UIAlertAction trigger a function?

Tags: swift, uialertaction

Is it possible to connect a function to an `UIAlertAction`?

So after a user clicks the **OK** button it performs an action? Isn't this what the handler parameter does?

```
let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email already registered", message: "Please enter a different email", preferredStyle: .alert)
let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: backToLogin())

alert.addAction(okButton)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

...

```
func backToLogin() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLoginPage", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Look your code format. It's terrible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function as the `handler`, but it needs to have the correct type. Also you must not call it when you pass it as an argument, i.e., instead of `handler: backToLogin()` (which would set the *return value* of `backToLogin` as the handler) you would have `handler: backToLogin` without the `()`.

The following should work:

```
func backToLogin(alertAction: UIAlertAction) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLoginPage", sender: self)
}
let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: backToLogin)
```

But having to change `backToLogin` might defeat the purpose, so you could just use a closure:

```
let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in
    self.backToLogin()
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks! I'm looking into closures more now...thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to enter the handler

let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {

(UIAlertAction) in

self.backToLogin()

})

}
```

See this answer for more info: [Writing handler for UIAlertAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190277/writing-handler-for-uialertaction)