# Swift alert handler syntax odd

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

One of my Swift code block is an alert popup:

```
func alertNewBillCreated() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Bill created and ready to be paid", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (UIAlertAction) in

        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }

    alert.addAction(actionOK)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Reading other SO posts like this: [Writing handler for UIAlertAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190277/writing-handler-for-uialertaction)

They all gave examples where the handler part is inclusive and explicitly defined, e.g.:

```
UIAlertAction(title: "Okay",
                      style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                    handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in println("Foo")
```

However, in my above code which I used Xcode's autocomplete to help me write the alert block, my version doesn't have the comma followed the `handler` key.

These two variations also works (in addition to my first block of code above):

```
let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
        ...            
    })
```

and

```
let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        ...
    })
```

What is this odd Swift syntax exception rule ?

Isn't this a bug ?

Do we not separate function parameters with commas ?

It looks to me like I'm calling a function `UIAlertAction()` and only passing it two parameters - `title` and `style` since there are only 2 commas:

`UIAlertAction(__ , __ ) { ... }`

Or is...this...the Swift equivalent of Ruby blocks? ([Best explanation of Ruby blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911353/best-explanation-of-ruby-blocks))

My alert code works, it's not broken, in case anyone is curious.

Seems a bit inconsistent with so many rules and odd syntax, making it hard/harder to remember the rules for Swift syntax and learning Swift.

Hopefully by Swift 4.0, all these things are ironed out...

Maybe I'm complaining too much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last parameter is a block it can be appended like a method body.

Read more.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94
Trailing Closures

Comment: So it's just syntactic sugar ?

Comment: You can call it that :)