# UIAlertAction - Handling Actions

Tags: ios, swift, handler, uialertaction

I have a helper to show my alerts

```
import UIKit

class AlertDialog {
    class func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, viewController: UIViewController) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How can I manage the actions in my View Controllers?

I am calling the func like this;

```
AlertDialog.showAlert("Ok", message: "Some Message", viewController: self)
```

I need to get the handler option. What do I change the "handler: nil" to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing handler for UIAlertAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190277/writing-handler-for-uialertaction)

Comment: the proposed duplicate is using the AlertAction within the View Controller as opposed to having a separate helper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two handlers parameters to your `showAlert` method, one for the ok action and another for the cancel action. So your code might look something like this:

```
class AlertDialog {
    class func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, viewController: UIViewController,
                     okHandler: (() -> Swift.Void),
                     cancelHandler: (() -> Swift.Void)) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: okHandler)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: cancelHandler)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

From your viewController you will call:

```
AlertDialog.showAlert("Ok", message: "Some Message", viewController: self, okHandler: {
            //OK Action
        },cancelAction: {
            //Cancel Action
        })
```

Comment: Given the question I think answer would benefit from showing an example of how the new parameters could be used.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
class func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, viewController: UIViewController, ok: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?, cancel: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?) {
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: ok)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: cancel)
}
```

And then you would use this as follows:

```
AlertDialog.showAlert("Ok", message: "Some Message", viewController: self, ok: { (alertAction) in 
    // do something for ok
}, cancel: { (alertAction) in
    // do something for cancel
})
```