# How to send a string to url?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm setting up a barcode reader app, got 3 tab bar item and one of them "SCAN" tab and another one of them is "WEBVIEW" tab. When user scan the barcode or qr, it's giving a string and going to webview's url. I want to send this string to url and open the webview tab. Can you help me with this problem ?

```
  if (metadataObjects.count > 0 && metadataObjects.first is AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) {

        let scan = metadataObjects.first as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Barkod Tarandı", message: scan.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)



        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "TAMAM", style: .default, handler:nil))



        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)



        if(scan.stringValue != nil)
        {
            if let aString = URL(string: "" + ("http://www.truebilisim.com/myiphone/true/mymagazaplus/barkod.php?barkod=\(scan.stringValue)")) {
                webalani.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: aString))
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What **is** the problem?

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: **What** is not working? Nobody can read your mind. Please add information what you expect and what happens.

Comment: it's giving me a alert message but doesn't go to webview tab with string when i click "TAMAM" button. string go but webview doesn't load or string doesn't go and webview doesn't load too ? i can't understand.

Comment: if you want to open the URL when the action button is tapped you have to put the code in the `handler` parameter of the action which is `nil`.

Comment: can you show me how i can ?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190277/writing-handler-for-uialertaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the NSURL it must work.

```
webalani.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "aString")!))
```

And make sure your this line must be NSURL too

```
if let aString = URL(string: "" + ("http://www.truebilisim.com/myiphone/true/mymagazaplus/barkod.php?barkod=\(scan.stringValue)")) {
```